# change url for static files in /wp-admin with a cdn url

Tags: customization, urls, cdn

I recently purchased a CDN and used a plugin to change the site url for all static files in the "/wp-content" and "/wp-include" folder to the cdn url.

Is there a way to change the site url for static files (espcially images) in the "/wp-admin" to a cdn url?

Comment: I think there is no easy way to change the URL of that files and I also think there is very little advantage of doing it for your users. In general, there are no static assets loaded from wp-admin in front-end.

Comment: I agree this is way more trouble that it's worth. Not to say it couldn't be done, but really a waste of time for "admin images" - I cannot even think of one? Unless by "static files" you are meaning admin stylesheets and javascripts? If so, update your question.

Comment: yes, i meant the css, javascript, and the image files in the "media library" section the wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `wp-includes` but you can quite easily change the URL of your `wp-content` folder by setting this constant in your `wp-config.php` file:

```php
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://mybucket.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com');
```

By default, the `WP_CONTENT_URL` constant is set to the URL of the `wp-content` directory of a WordPress installation. However, it can be customized to point to a different URL or domain, which can be useful in certain scenarios, such as when you want to serve your static content from a CDN or a subdomain.

https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#moving-wp-content-folder